# Equivalent java code for this kotlin code?

Tags: java

I have this kotlin code:

```
private fun showNoMoreCards() = showContent {
    row {
        label(gapLeft = LEFT_MARGIN, text = "Congratulations, you've reviewed all the cards for now!")
    }
}

fun showContent(init: LayoutBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    val panel = panel(LCFlags.fill) {
        init()
    }

    val content = ContentFactory.SERVICE.getInstance().createContent(panel, "", false)
    toolWindow.contentManager.removeAllContents(false)
    toolWindow.contentManager.addContent(content)
}
```

```

I don't understand nor want to learn kotlin, I'd like this in Java. There is a lot of this code, I just need some guidance on what this would look like with (presumably) JPanels and the like - can someone give me the roughly equivalent java code?

This code is found in [this github repo](https://github.com/denvned/idea-flashcards/tree/master/src/org/intellij/flashcards)

Comment: @JaysonMinard unsure what you're flummoxed by, there is already a great answer. Take the time to read it, the answerer has correctly assessed my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this might be slightly off, but it's the best that I can do with the amount of code that's provided in Java 8 (and without actually reading through the provided Github repo):

```
private void showNoMoreCards() {
    showContent((layoutBuilder) -> {
        layoutBuilder.row((rowBuilder) -> {
            rowBuilder.label(LEFT_MARGIN, "Congratulations, you've reviewed all the cards for now!");
        });
    }); 
}

public void showContent(java.util.function.Consumer<LayoutBuilder> init) {
    JPanel panel = panel(LCFlags.fill, () -> {
        init.apply(layoutBuilder);
    });

    Content content = ContentFactory.SERVICE.getInstance().createContent(panel, "", false)
    toolWindow.getContentManager().removeAllContents(false);
    toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(content);
}
```